# Is there a point to make repository lazy?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lazy-evaluation, lazy-initialization

I'm interested in knowing how long does it take to instantiate a new instance in my project, is there some kind of tool for doing that? Or just put log after ctor that prints time is good enough?

I wanna know if there's a difference in time between creating a new regular c# public class vs generic class such as Repository in order to decide if there is any point at all to make it lazy:

Lets say I have a service that is injected with all my application's repositories per request:

```
public class DataService
{
   private IRepository<Folder> _folders;
   private IRepository<Folder> _letters;

   // Gets repositories per request
   public DataService(IRepository<Folder> foldersRepo, IRepository<Letter> lettersRepo..........)
   {
       _letters = lettersRepo;
       _folders = foldersRepo;
   }
}

public IRepository<T> where T: BaseEntityObject
{
    void Add(T entity);

    void Remove(T entity);

    List<T> Get();

    T FindById(int id);

    int SaveChanges();

    void Dispose(); 
}


public abstract class EFRepository<T> : IRepository<T>
{
    protected readonly DbContext Context;

    public EFRepository(DbContext context)
    {
        Context = context;
    }

    public abstract List<T> Get();

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        Context.Set<T>().Add(item);
    }

    public void Remove(T item)
    {
        Context.Set<T>().Remove(item);
    }

    public void Update(T item)
    {
        Context.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Context.Dispose();
    }

    public int SaveChanges()
    {
        return Context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public T FindById(int id)
    {
        return Context.Set<T>().Find(id); 
    }
}


public LettersRepository : EFRepository<Letter>
{
    public LettersRepository(DbContext context) : base(context) {}

    // Override for case includes will be needed in future
    public override List<T> Get()
    {
        return Context.Set<T>().ToList();
    }
}

public FoldersRepository : EFRepository<Folder>
{
    public FoldersRepository(DbContext context) : base(context) {}

    public override List<T> Get()
    {
        return Context.Set<T>().Include("Letters").ToList();
    }
}
```

Is there any point at all for getting those repositories as Lazy - meaning they will be instantiated at first usage? I've been thinking about it since I don't use all of those repositories at each request, usually I use only one.

Comment: You're going to talk to a _database_, over a _network_. Any optimization you're going to do to make class instantiation any nanoseconds faster is **not going to be any significant improvement** over the time it takes to actually execute the query and fetch the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm interested in knowing how long does it take to instantiate a new instance in my project, is there some kind of tool for doing that?

The tool is called a [profiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)).

> Or just put log after ctor that prints time is good enough?

Class instantiation is, in the vast majority of cases (i.e. unless there's heavy processing in the class's constructor), such a fast operation that it makes hardly any sense to bother with that.

> I wanna know if there's a difference in time between creating a new regular c# public class vs generic class

There's no significant difference.

> Is there any point at all for getting those repositories as Lazy - meaning they will be instantiated at first usage? I've been thinking about it since I don't use all of those repositories at each request, usually I use only one.

From a performance perspective: this will be [premature optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize). Just don't worry, unless you are instantiating like a million of them. *However,* from a software design perspective, it *does make sense* to instantiate only those repositories that are really needed. You are effectively reducing the surface of the problem — there's less to break and care of at the given time.

Answer (score 1):

If you interested how to make an injected property lazy - some DI containers support that, for example: https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.Factory/wiki/Lazy

Creation cost of your repository is low. Cause `DbContext` cost is [relatively low too](http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2011/04/15/code-first-inside-dbcontext-initialization/):

> Not very much happens when the context instance is created. The
>   initialization is mostly lazy so that if you never use the instance,
>   then you pay very little cost for creating the instance.

Also context-per-request is a common practice.